# Error codes "NameError 'User' is not defined' I am trying to populate the database

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

## 1. Error codes "NameError 'User' is not defined

```
import random
from datetime import datetime
from auction.models import Auction, Bid
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()


def populate_db():
   entries = 50
   for i in range(1, entries+1):
      username = 'user_%d' % i
      password = username
      email = '%s@yaas.com' % username
      print ("Creating new user username=%s, email=%s, password=%s" % (username, email, password))

      new_user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
      year = random.randint(1975, 2025)
      month = random.randint(1, 12)
      day = random.randint(1, 28)
      .....     
      .....
      .....
 populate_db()
```

Any Suggetions ? I use django 2.0.4.
Is there a way to check whether the user auth model was imported? If yes, what can I do in case it was not correctly imported?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `User.objects.create()` as

```
User.objects.create(username=username, email=email, password=password)
```

instead of writing `create_user()`

To check if `get_user_model`  is mapped properly you can follow these steps:

Open management shell

```
python manage.py shell
```

Run below commands:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

Now you can check if you can interact with model or not by executing queries like get, filter, create etc.

Comment: **Thanks!** I can interact with the model now! But after trying using      `create_user()`  did not change anything..so still it does not work

Comment: if you are using default database you don't need to be use `using`

Comment: I can interact with the model now! But after trying    `create_user()`  did not change anything..so still it does not work

Comment: Are you using built in user model or you have override it?

Comment: I am using built in  user model

Comment: use `create` method instead of using `create_user` however you can import user model directly as `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` this way you don't even need to call for `get_user_model`